# MySQL default queries

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, navicat

Since yesterday I have been using navicat monitor to see what frequently used querys are in my database.
Now it appears that with the slow query log it is mainly querys that are done by the database itself. The two that have already been executed 55000 times within 12 hours are as follows:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(event_name, '/', -1) AS wait_type
     , sum_timer_wait / 1000000000000 AS wait_time 
  FROM performance_schema.events_stages_summary_global_by_event_name 
 WHERE ( sum_timer_wait / 1000000000000 ) > 0.01

SELECT a.digest 
     , a.thread_id session_id
     , USER db_user
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX( HOST, ':', 1 ) machine
     , db db_name
     , ATTR_VALUE program
     , sum( timer_wait ) timer_wait 
  FROM performance_schema.events_statements_history a 
  LEFT 
  JOIN performance_schema.threads b 
    ON a.THREAD_ID = b.THREAD_ID 
  LEFT 
  JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST c 
    ON b.PROCESSLIST_ID = c.ID 
  LEFT   
  JOIN performance_schema.session_connect_attrs d
    ON c.id = d.PROCESSLIST_ID 
 WHERE timer_wait/1000000000 > 0.5 
   and a.sql_text IS NOT NULL 
   AND ( d.ATTR_NAME = "_client_name" OR d.ATTR_NAME IS NULL ) 
 GROUP 
    BY a.thread_id
     , a.digest
     , db_user
     , machine
     , program
     , db_name
```

Now my question is what do these do? And are these not superfluous, as if they cannot stop? And if so how?

Comment: You rarely never need to combine SELECT DISTINCT with GROUP BY.

Comment: Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read - and to write!

Comment: I didn't made these queries. They've been executed but i don't know why

Comment: Simple.  Turn of the performance_schema.  (See the documentation on how.)